# Running a basic JHipster monilithic app with no entities returns a blank page

Tags: angular, jhipster

I had JHipster (version 4.14.4) running fine but while attempting to learn Angular 5, also installed Angular. Now when I try to create a JHipster app, I get the following errors and only get a blank page in the browser:

```
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency 
"popper.js@^1.12.9".
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
```

And later:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-detail.component.ts:23:9 
TS90010: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Property '_parent' is protected but type 'Subscription' is not a class derived from 'Subscription'.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Is there a way to delete everything pertaining to JHipster and Angular and start over? Or does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Based on the discussion in a related issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7554, you should delete your node_modules folder and re-run `yarn install` and `yarn start`

Comment: I tried that but it still generates the same issue. I uninstalled jhipster and npm and reinstalled from scratch, but still get the same problem.